# Why do parts of my model look really bad when I shade smooth? And how can I fix this?

Tags: shaders

**Why do parts of my model look really bad when I shade smooth? And how can I fix this?**

When I shade smooth parts of my model look pretty good and others look quite bad (I don't mean the shape I mean the texture). It can be seen in my model below where the part highlighted looks good and the one highlighted in red doesn't, how could I make the red part look and have the same texture as the green part.
[image]

Comment: Correct shading in blender is heavily topology dependent - blender favors quad based topology and often gives shading artifacts when attempting to smooth shade tri's and n-gon's. Make sure your mesh is made mostly (if not all) of quads (especially near curved edges), and that sections have the necessary supporting geometry.

Comment: Do you have Auto Smooth turned on in Object Data Properties?

Comment: I'm not sure, I think I just did shade smooth in object mode for the whole mesh.